# The method is undefined for the type ImmutableList<String>

Tags: java, json

The code is download from others project. At line 4 the reverse() function has an error. The content is "`The method reverse() is undefined for the type ImmutableList<String>`"

I know the meaning of error, but I don't know how to deal with it. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
public static <T> JsonExtractor<T> generateExtractor(String path, JsonExtractor<T> rootExtractor, boolean exceptionOnOutOfBounds) {
    ImmutableList<String> tokens = ImmutableList.copyOf(new JsonPathTokenizer(path));
    JsonExtractor<T> jsonExtractor = rootExtractor;
    for (String token : tokens.reverse()) {
        jsonExtractor = new ObjectFieldJsonExtractor<>(token, jsonExtractor, exceptionOnOutOfBounds);
    }
    return jsonExtractor;
}
```

The code import is

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
```

Comment: You want to iterate over the list, but starting at the end. Modify the loop to reflect that.

Comment: Which `ImmutableList` are you takling about? It does not seem to be [Guava's `ImmutableList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/11.0.2/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html), since this one defines a `reverse()`-method. Voting to close as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Why loop at all? Why not just use `tokens.get(0)`?

Comment: because the new `jsonExtractor` uses the old `jsonExtractor`.

Comment: I'm a freshman on ImmutableList. Is there has multiple different ImmutableList? And how can I figure out which ImmutableList is? the code import is `import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the items in the list from last to first.

```
for (int index = tokens.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    String token = tokens.get(index);
    jsonExtractor = new ObjectFieldJsonExtractor<>(token, jsonExtractor, exceptionOnOutOfBounds);
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes that (a) there is a `size()` method in `ImmutableList` and (b) that there is a `get(int index)` method in `ImmutableList`. As long as OP does not specifiy which `ImmutableList` s/he is using, this answer is speculative.